# why we need DefaultAuthenticateScheme when we already have DefaultScheme in authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

we have two "default" scheme in `AuthenticationOptions` as:

```
public class AuthenticationOptions
{
   // ...
   public string? DefaultScheme { get; set; }
   public string? DefaultAuthenticateScheme { get; set; }
{
```

based on the answer from [What is the point of configuring DefaultScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme on ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492666/what-is-the-point-of-configuring-defaultscheme-and-defaultchallengescheme-on-asp) we know that

- Authenticate: DefaultAuthenticateScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Challenge: DefaultChallengeScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Forbid: DefaultForbidScheme, or DefaultChallengeScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Sign-in: DefaultSignInScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Sign-out: DefaultSignOutScheme, or DefaultScheme

my question is, when we need `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` when we already have DefaultScheme in authentication? can't we make the above summary as:

- Authenticate: DefaultScheme
- Challenge: DefaultChallengeScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Forbid: DefaultForbidScheme, or DefaultChallengeScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Sign-in: DefaultSignInScheme, or DefaultScheme
- Sign-out: DefaultSignOutScheme, or DefaultScheme

so we just need to have one and only default `IAuthenticationHandler` and this `IAuthenticationHandler`'s `AuthenticateAsync()` has the code we want to use to authenticate users?

Answer (score 0):

You could use methods like this

```
await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal);
```

You could also omit the scheme parameters like this. Then they will use the corresponding default "schemes" implicitly.

```
await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync();
await HttpContext.ForbidAsync();
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

You could set these default scheme like this.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}
```

Or simply like below. It will have the same effect as above.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}
```

Or maybe you want to set the all the other schemes to "cookie" . But for `AuthenticateAsync` you want use "jwt" as default.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}
```

Well I don't think this is a good idea in any situation.