# Unable to make Microsoft Graph API request in ASP.NET Core with Microsoft Identity for authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-web

I am working on an ASP.NET Core application using Microsoft Identity for authentication. The application is configured with both cookie authentication and Microsoft Identity Web for Azure AD authentication. However, when I attempt to make a request to Microsoft Graph API using the following code:

`var res = await GraphClient.Me.Events.Request().GetAsync();`

I encounter the following exception:

Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.

Upon further investigation, the inner exception provides the following information:

IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was ''. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred 'Cookies' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication schemes are 'Cookies,AzureAd'. See https://aka.ms/id-web/authSchemes.

Here is the relevant part of my Startup.cs authentication configuration:

```
var authentication = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/LoginPage";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
});

authentication
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), Microsoft.Identity.Web.Constants.AzureAd, null)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' '))
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

It seems like there is an issue with the authentication scheme. I have both 'Cookies' and 'AzureAd' schemes configured. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully make requests to Microsoft Graph API.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that both 'Cookies' and 'AzureAd' authentication schemes are properly configured in the Startup.cs file.

Checked and confirmed that the GraphClient is properly initialized and authenticated with the required scopes.

Reviewed the Microsoft Identity for Web documentation and related issues on GitHub to see if there are any known solutions or workarounds.

Verified that the 'DownstreamApi: Scopes' configuration in Startup.cs matches the required scopes for Microsoft Graph API.

Expected Outcome:

I expect that the authentication process should successfully determine the cloud instance and allow me to make requests to Microsoft Graph API without encountering the 'IDW10503' error.

Comment: I wonder if setting the default auth schema would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492666/what-is-the-point-of-configuring-defaultscheme-and-defaultchallengescheme-on-asp

Comment: My issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @BabarKhalid do you have any update on this issue?

Comment: I just changed the code in the question a little bit. Can you please update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this code pls:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PrivacyAsync()
{
    var me = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request()
        .WithAuthenticationScheme(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

It worked in my side.

[image]

In my program.cs, I defined the 2 authentication schemes like below. Just like you see, I defined the `openIdConnectScheme` as `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` so that I also need to clearify it in my graph client.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/account/login");
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "ADCookies")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();   
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Comment: How can I do this using only one authentication? like : 
var authentication = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/LoginPage";
});

authentication
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), Microsoft.Identity.Web.Constants.AzureAd, null)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' '))
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Comment: I just changed the code in the question a little bit. Can you please update accordingly?